# Unidirectional continuous data transfer to an air-gapped computer

Tags: network, firewalls, air-gap, data-transfer

What would be a way to transfer files in one direction from **internet-facing computerA => air-gapped computerB** to protect the files on computerB from unauthorised disclosure, short of using an expensive data-diode?

Requirements

1. The data transfer must be continuous. (cable is ok but not a USB flash drive)
2. Only the confidentiality of data in computerB is important. There is no need to protect the integrity of data in computerB.

Consider that computerA may be at a risk of being compromised. What would be the best way to transfer data (mostly pdf files) in one direction? I'm looking for a solution that mostly protects against remote attacks (i.e. confidential files end up on compromised computerA) rather than local attacks (attacker is a few metres from the setup).

Comment: you could make a folder for the sensitive info with write-only perms. you could also put up a 2nd internet-connected computer, that shares a non-network connection with B, like a serial port, and use a small script to push data over the serial connection into a file on B. That would render OS/malware/network exploits moot, at the cost of complexity and bandwidth.

Comment: Your added details require more explanation. How does transferring files in one direction protect either computer? What do you want to protect? So what if ComputerA is compromised?

Comment: There is no need to protect either computer. Unidirectional transfer is required to protect the confidentiality of files in computerB - which is what data diodes typically do.

Comment: This is a classic XY problem. You want to protect Y (the files on computerB), so you explore securing X (the file transfer process from computerA). But these concepts do not connect. You want a simple firewall on computerB. And computerB is not air-gapped if it is connected  to the network...

Comment: @schroeder A data diode (one-way air gap) is the gold-standard method to protect the confidentiality of files on computer B, is it not? Other methods sacrifice confidentiality for usability.

Comment: @dandavis, a file share protocol is still bidirectional—thus fails when exploited.  I've used this to one-way store files.  However, there are enough issues when using that method legitimately (e.g. duplicate named files?)—I would highly discourage using this method at all.

Comment: The answers provided for unidirectional data transfer are adequate; however I'd encourage some thought toward "There is no need to protect either computer" - you might not leak data out, however these solutions do not protect computer B from malicious intent.  If A is compromised even a one way signal can be used to exploit B for data deletion, data modification, or similar nefarious deeds.  As an example since both top answers are UDP... hypothetical malformed UDP packets could exploit hypothetical bugs in the network stack to execute arbitrary code.  Consider your requirements carefully.

Comment: @Doug: OP only seems to care about B's exfiltration, not corruption.

Comment: I made something like this using a sequence of QR codes as a "modem" to pass one-time-pads between phones. A good webcam pointed at a good monitor should be able to pass the full 4kb per code, probably at a rate of at least 10hz, maybe more depending on framerates and CPU. It's not the simplest method, but it might be the cheapest since it uses existing hardware.

Comment: Wait, data diodes are expensive? I'm used to making them by taking a serial cable and clipping off a pin.

Answer (score 39):

I've seen this implemented many times in secure environments:

Simply connect the two computers via optical fiber and disconnect one side of the fiber.

That guarantees your one-way connect.

Protocol wise, the connection uses **UDP** protocol with a:

1. Start-Block
2. Data-Block
3. Stop-Block
4. Checksum-Block

Typically the Start and Stop are whole files, not chunks.

The Receiver simply checksums the data and compares with the checksum sent. If it matches, you're done. If not, the receiver indicates an error that has to be manually checked with the User having to manually re-send because there is no automated feedback.

This simplistic approach works quite well because with a direct fiber one-to-one connect, classic concerns about UDP mostly don't happen.

- Order is guaranteed because it's completely sequential.
- Reliability while not assured, is extremely high without network contention.
- Verification only requires a simple checksum.

Some systems opted for multiple retransmissions as a simplistic error correction but errors are rare with a direct connect.

Comment: Exactly. Given the bandwidth of a typical optical link, it's easy to send the same data 1000+ times (with a grown-up hash instead of a short checksum that can fail to detect some types of corruption) and thus practically eliminate the potential failed transfers. Just make it resend each data block every minute for 24 hours or so and you get something that's very resilient against all kinds of issues.

Comment: Note: for eye safety reasons, there should be a rubber stopper in the unused fiber transmitter.

Comment: (Also, this constitutes a *cheap* data diode)

Comment: @user253751 Not just for eye safety, but also to prevent said expensive transmitter from getting ruined by lots of dust getting in there.

Comment: Not sure if this is still relevent, but back when I was implementing this type of thing with fibre optic network cards nearly 20 years ago, they needed to see a carrier on the Rx port in order to send data out the Tx port. This meant you'd need a second card on your sending box looping back its Tx to the Rx of the card that you want to send data to the other box with.

Comment: @TooTea Well, "expensive" could be as little as $10 (if you buy from companies of questionable repute which may have extra chips installed by Chinese spy agencies)

Comment: @user253751 Have you ever used optics IRL? They are incredibly low power. Your typical 10km/40km SFP+ module has a lower IR radiant energy density than a light bulb. Don't spread FUD about laser safety

Comment: @Navin I'm repeating what I was taught about optic safety when I had to set some up. The beam is invisible, can reflect off things, and it's also all concentrated into one spot instead of being spread out, so I'm not taking my chances.

Comment: We also had an incident where an (RF, not optical) cable wasn't plugged in and the signal managed to bounce around the metal enclosure to the intended receiver *anyway*. So: terminate your connectors, or your data diode might not actually be one-way!

Comment: @user253751 I said "radiant energy density". If you focus a beam, the energy density goes up while the power stays the same. In other words, I've taken into account that the beam is more concentrated. btw the output is not totally invisible; Every module  emits a small amount of visible light. This is a manufacturing defect, but it's very useful for debugging. Look for it the next time you're in a data center. To be clear, I'm talking about optics that you plug into switches. Higher power optics exist, but they are externally powered. That's probably what your instructor was talking about.

Comment: Do data diodes have any advantages of the crippled serial port cable approach that @user4574 suggested?

Answer (score 21):

Use a serial port with the TX pin removed on computer B.

You can send the data but no matter what happens you physically can't get it out of computer B without the TX pin.

Comment: Don't remove the pin, remove the wire in the cable. You never know when you might want to use that port for something else later.

Comment: I've done this on several occasions, it's easy and inexpensive.  Your transfer speed is a bit limited, but still plenty fast for many use cases.

Comment: @user253751 I had intended to mean that the pin in the cable be removed, but that is a good clarification.  For astandard PC serial port, the cable usually has pins and the PC side is usually a sockets.

Comment: I don't think you need to remove TX, which could be needed for flow control. An exploit that usefully alters an already-running program that has exclusive access to B's serial port, as well as a new incoming serial handler on A to exfiltrate, seems basically impossible. If eve could devise that, you might as well give up.

Comment: @dandavis The TX is not needed for flow control, flow control is done over pins RTS and CTS, which could be skipped like the other pins. If missing, the transmitter doesn't know if the target has enough space in its buffers. You really only need GND and RX with serial on side A, and TX and GND at the other side. (Source: I have 2 USB to serial adapters laying around here, and this is the bare minimum needed to make 2 devices talk)

Comment: @dandavis Data diodes are about absolute security, you physically don't give B a way to communicate with A. You don't rely on the software that's on B or A.

Comment: Dumb question probably, but if you connect 2 (say, Linux) computers using a serial port cable, how would you actually send a file from one machine to another?

Answer (score 9):

You can use a packet filter and a custom UDP service to make file transfer, but I believe you want something that isn't even needed.

Have Computer B sit behind a router with firewall configured. The firewall allows traffic in, but drops traffic out. That's why you need an UDP service, as TCP would have to send confirmation data out, and that's forbidden.

Your UDP service would have to receive the filename, the file size, and a Merkle tree with the hashes of the chunks. You need to cut the file in small chunks because UDP does not guarantee the order, or even that the packets will even be received. Every chunk would need to have its sequence order, size, and hash. Send the chunks one after the other, with a delay between each one.

On the receiving site, the service will have to get all chunks, hash them, put them in order, and calculate the Merkle tree to see if the file was sent without problems. If the file is in order, save it. If not, discard it because there's no way to tell the sending side that the file was not send correctly.

Comment: You could actually also use TCP if you configure the firewall to only allow outbound TCP packets without a payload. While in theory that could create a side-channel to exfiltrate data from B, actually pulling that off by gaining remote code execution on B through a single-purpose unidirectional dumb link like this is likely nearly impossible.

Comment: @TooTea That sounds painful to configure. Even if you only allow SYN/ACK, TCP is complicated and has plenty of slots where you can exfiltrate data such as the sequence number. When OP said "air-gapped", I'm pretty sure he is referring to a physical barrier that prevents exfiltration even if B is compromised.

Comment: A router (that could be any computer, really), or a managed switch that supports access-lists that would let you drop everything received on computer B's port. Of course the router or switch should not allow any management access from either A or B, and any possible bugs in their software would become part of the problem.

Answer (score 8):

You can try "unidirectional" network cables: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/279257/implement-send-only-one-way-ethernet-cable

A speedy DIY data diode can be built for 100-200 bucks with a pair of media converters + a fiber optic splitter. As software, you can use udpcast. You can also find some other DIY setups including software on the webs.
Note that a data diode won't protect B against attacks. (Excluding side channels) it will only prevent data from flowing back.

There is also some ongoing project:
https://www.thehaguesecuritydelta.com/projects/project/99-open-source-data-diode
But nothing has been published as far as I know.

Also if A is compromised how do you "trust" the data coming from A?

Answer (score 2):

Do not try to write your own.
Use a protocol that already does this.

- [NORM/NORP](https://www.nrl.navy.mil/itd/ncs/products/norm)
- [FLUTE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6726)